# Issue with angular material 2 in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am trying to add angular material2 to my project. (I use angular-cli)
However, I get the following error when I run `ng serve`:

> material.es5.js:177 Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Although I added it to my global style file.

```css
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't their file a .scss file ? you imported a css file.

Comment: you can try to include the following in your index.html head : `<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Yes, but I have an error, that it can not find it : GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css

Comment: Is you style file a `*.css` or a `*.scss` file? And did you import it to your styles object in `.angular-cli.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `angular-cli.json` under :

```
"apps": [

  //....

"styles": [

   //... , 

  "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" //<--add this
  ],
]
```