# Angular Material 2 Could not find core theme

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I know this is repeated question, but none of the solutions listed have helped me. I am getting the following error in Console: `Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming`

What I have already done:

- Added style key in angular-cli.json [Suggested Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44156582/1444181)
- Tried real path to CSS [Suggested Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44436391/1444181)

And few others. I seem to have lost the tabs.

Now the thing that intrigues me is that I have the styles loaded as seen from here.

[image: Screenshot]

So is the class that material checks for: `mat-theme-loaded-marker`.

But I still can't seem to get it to load. Same error.

My AppModule is as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import 'hammerjs';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/app';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: '**', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    ),
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [ CookieService],
  bootstrap: [ LoginComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

PS: I am new to angular 4.

Comment: Btw: you do not do `MaterialModule` anymore. Instead you just include the modules of the components you need like `MdButtonModule` and so on. Take a look here: [Getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

Comment: what is the sequence of `stylesheets import`? update the css includes to your post

Comment: @pzaenger yeah i initially tried that, same error. Hence stuck to this.

Comment: @Aravind there is only one import. Nothing else.

Comment: Guys I got it to work but it looks more like a hack rather then working. I added the stylesheet, the CSS, to the `assets` folder, added its location in `angular-cli.json` and voila it works. Now the real question, why does this work and the method provided in the Docs doesn't?

Comment: add this line in style.css `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Comment: I have already done that. I somehow forgot to mention this in my question. The theme is getting registered but not soon enough for material to know its loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Developing Angular 2 with material design , we need to use some default css from the material component other wise it will show console error in your browser like **Could not find Angular Material core theme.**.To avoid these problem we need to use one of the default theme in your material component.From the below image you can observe **4** prebuilt-themses in youe node_module.[image]

. I am importing one of the themes in my **styles.css** file. Please look into below screen shot.After that reload the page then you can see there no error message show in your browser console. I hope it will help for you.[image]

Comment: My setup is same, except the custom styles. The problem is not the CSS file, it gets loaded but i guess after the material has checked.
This is my css: http://imgur.com/a/WB0Xa

Comment: Forgot to say, still the same error. I added the `body` style after reading your answer.

Comment: I am down voting your answer for the following reasons: the css is being loaded as displayed in the image in question; the import command is mentioned in the question above and in the comment where i specify it is the only command in the css file.